# How can I mute warnings for unused parameters in method implementation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, appcode

Using AppCode 108.1068, developing an iOS app with cocos2d, I often end up implementing methods for a selector, and it goes like this:

```
-(void) sequenceStateSelectSkillByCPU:(ccTime) dt{
    if (cycleCount_==1) {
        touchHandler_.isEnabled=NO;
        isSequencingSkillsChoice_=YES;
        [self interruptScheduling];
        [self flyOut];
        [master_ taskComplete:@"skillsChoice"];

    }
}
```

I keep getting the warning about unused variable (dt, i Know, i prefer having full control over my state handling rather than relying on dt). I am implementing a method that complies to a protocol that shoves **dt** on me, in all circumstances, whether i need it or not.

Was wondering where/how to mute that specific warning.

Comment: Xcode doesn't warn you about not using parameters. AppCode I don't care for so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the inspection to check off is 'unused local variables' ... which unfortunately also stops the useful 'unused local variables'for variables declared inside the body of the method.

Comment: that's because function parameters ARE local variables ;)
You can work around that by just writing: dt;  (variable followed by semicolon). Although with some other compiler warning this may cause an "ineffective statement" warning or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to hide compiler warnings. But sometimes it's really complicated to find out my warnigs among huge number of warnings from other frameworks or built-in projects. Anyway if any one want to supress those "unused" compliler warnigs then open project's build settings and change the compilation flags.

[image]

Comment: app code question. By and large, i agree with your statement about good practice. However , as @Sold Out Activist could say, i have no use for xCode. thank you for the time though.